# gesture recognizer issue with tic tac toe in xcode

Tags: swift

hello there i am trying to figure out what the issue is why i cant get a cross on the game board when a tap is made. the TTT class is the one below the first code and it is called in the main code. i will appreciate if some can help me on this

```
@IBOutlet var fields: [TTTImageView]!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}




func fieldTapped (recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer)    {
        let tappedField = recognizer.view as! TTTImageView
    tappedField.setPlayer(_player: "x.png")


}



func setupField ()  {
    for index in 0 ... fields.count - 1 {

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(fieldTapped))
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        fields[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)


    }

}
```

import UIKit

class TTTImageView: UIImageView {

```
var player:String?
var activated:Bool! = false

func setPlayer  (_player:String)    {
    self.player = _player

    if activated == false   {
        if _player == "x.png"   {
            self.image = UIImage (named: "x.png")
        }else{
            self.image = UIImage (named: "o.png")
        }
        activated = true
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you set `fields[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)` to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`.

```
fields[index].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Whenever you want to detect user activity (e.g. `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a `UIImageView`, you need to set this to `true`

EDIT:

I also wanted to mention something I noticed after looking at your code again: the method you are using for selectors has been deprecated. If you are using Swift 3 (which I highly recommend you do), you shouldn't call selectors like this: `"functionName:"` anymore. Now we use selectors like so: `#selector(functionName(_:))`. You should start updating your code to the most current syntax sooner rather than later.

Comment: hello Pierce, thanks for your response, well appreciated. However, i corrected both errors you spotted but to my surprise it still doesnt work. please look through the code if there is something i am missing again..regards

Comment: @user2989434 - I assumed your object `TTTImageView` is a subclass of `UIImageView` is that the case here? Or is it something else?

Comment: @user2989434 - Would you post more of your code please? I would like to see where you append the values in your `fields:[TTTImageView]` array, and also how your custom `TTTImageView` is initialized. How do you call `init(frame:)`?